# Compare select values and show alert if they match

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 4 dropdowns from which you have to select an option.

What I am trying to do is show an alert if you chose the same option more than once. Its purpose is to keep the score for a game so a person shouldn't be able to play as 2.

At the moment the dropdown looks like this:

```
<select id="users_1" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <option>Select player</option>
    <?php foreach($users as $user) : ?>
    <option value="<?=$user['id_user']?>"><a href="#"><?=$user['nume']?></a></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

And what I've tried to do in JQuery is this:

```
$("#users_2").change(function() {
    var a=$(this).val("#users_1");
    var b=$(this).val("#users_2");
    if(a == b) {
        alert($(this).val());
    }
});
```

And I also tried to compare them like this:

```
$("#users_2").change(function() {
    if($(this).val() == $("#users_1").val()) {
        alert($(this).val());
    }
});
```

None seems to work and I have no clue why. I've checked and the actual values are taken from the view but the if clause cannot compare them apparently.

Thank you for any help! Much appreciated!

Comment: looks fine. Can you reproduce the problem in a fiddle?

Comment: second one would work.

Comment: Yes of course! This is a fiddle of something simmilar and the same as in my case, nothing happens and I don't know why.   https://jsfiddle.net/0c5xLxa9/

Comment: @VladEugenNitu you have not selected the jQuery library from the side top left. https://jsfiddle.net/0c5xLxa9/1/ check this its working.

Comment: @VladEugenNitu, you need to inlcude jquery. Its working here https://jsfiddle.net/0c5xLxa9/2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Get your values, don't set them

Change this…

```
$("#users_2").change(function() {
    var a=$(this).val("#users_1");
    var b=$(this).val("#users_2");
    if(a == b) {
        alert($(this).val());
    }
});
```

…to this…

```
$("#users_2").change(function() {
    var a = $("#users_1").val();
    var b = $(this).val(); // equivalent to $("#users_2").val()
    if(a === b) {          // Use strict comparison operator as a best practice
        alert(a + ' matches ' + b);
    }
});
```

### Make it dynamic

You can take it a step farther by listening to a set of elements and making your handler dynamic:

```js
// Listen to set of all select elements.
$('select').on('change', function(e) {
  
  // Serialize form values.
  var vals = $('#select_player').serializeArray();
  
  // Convert to simple array of just values.
  vals = $.map(vals, function (val, i) {
    return val.value;
  });
  
  // Remove current selection from array…
  vals.splice(vals.indexOf($(this).val()), 1);
  
  // …then check to see if it's value was already there.
  if(vals.indexOf($(this).val()) !== -1) { // If value is found,
    
    // …reset current select element to default option,
    $(this).val('default');
    
    // …and alert user with a relevant message.
    alert('You cannot select this player more than once.');
  };
});
```

```css
label {
  display: block;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="select_player" name="select_player">
  <label>Player 1:
    <select id="users_1" name="users_1">
      <option value="default" selected="selected" disabled>Select player</option>
      <option value="uid001">John Doe</option>
      <option value="uid002">Jane Doe</option>
      <option value="uid003">Jerome Smith</option>
      <option value="uid004">Janet O'Public</option>
    </select>
  </label>

  <label>Player 2:
    <select id="users_2" name="users_2">
      <option value="default" selected="selected" disabled>Select player</option>
      <option value="uid001">John Doe</option>
      <option value="uid002">Jane Doe</option>
      <option value="uid003">Jerome Smith</option>
      <option value="uid004">Janet O'Public</option>
    </select>
  </label>

  <label>Player 3:
    <select id="users_3" name="users_3">
      <option value="default" selected="selected" disabled>Select player</option>
      <option value="uid001">John Doe</option>
      <option value="uid002">Jane Doe</option>
      <option value="uid003">Jerome Smith</option>
      <option value="uid004">Janet O'Public</option>
    </select>
  </label>

  <label>Player 4:
    <select id="users_4" name="users_4">
      <option value="default" selected="selected" disabled>Select player</option>
      <option value="uid001">John Doe</option>
      <option value="uid002">Jane Doe</option>
      <option value="uid003">Jerome Smith</option>
      <option value="uid004">Janet O'Public</option>
    </select>
  </label>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! As you probably noticed I am still a beginner but I am getting a hold of it step by step. Unfortunately this is still not working for me, though I see it is working on jsfiddle. This is very weird. I forgot to mention that I am using CodeIgniter Framework but I doubt this is of much importance in this case as other scripts are running well.

Comment: Actually I managed to get it work. It was because of a PHP error, not the JQuery. Thank you very much for your support!

Comment: Any chance you also know how I can do so that if an alert occurs the select which produced the alert shows again the initial value ("Select player")???

Answer (score 2):

I used the same class on all the dropdowns and then use only one event handler.

```
$('.dropdown').on('change', function (event) {
    var selectedValue = $(event.currentTarget).val();
    var matchedDropdowns = $('.dropdown').filter(function (index) {
      return $(this).val() === selectedValue;
    });
    if (matchedDropdowns.length > 1) {
      alert("Alert Alert!")
    }
  })
```

In the event handlers I can get the selected value, filter all the dropdowns that match that value and if I get more than 1 dropdown I will just show the alert.

You can check it on [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lmuntaner/xoepozmt/).

Comment: I like the use of `filter` for reduced logic. Good call.